# breakable textfield

Tags: hyperref, pdf, input, textfield

is there any way to have a fillable textfield which is breakable across two pages, i.e. not
to be forced to one page only?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}

\begin{document}
\item \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  \TextField[width=18cm,height=1240pt, charsize=12pt,bordercolor=1 1 1,multiline=true,name=Partei1]{}}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,

Comment: Unrelated, but I think, your MWE contains things that are not relevant for this question. Also, The `\item` command should be inside a list environment.

Comment: Thank you @JasperHabicht. I admit not having tried the TextField alone, I will be more cutious next time. Thanks for the remark on the item, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that multi-page form fields exist, but you can automatically place the focus in the second field if the first field is full (this idea is actually taken from the [Acrobat JS API](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/jsapiref/JS_API_AcroJS.html#fieldfull)). For this, you'd need to deactivate scrolling for the relevant field via tha `donotscroll` option and add a small JavaScript to the `keystroke` option (I removed the `bordercolor` option to make the fields visible in the PDF):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[width=10cm, height=10cm, charsize=12pt, 
        multiline=true, name=Partei1a, keystroke={%
            if(event.fieldFull){ 
                this.getField("Partei1b").value = event.changeEx;
                this.getField("Partei1b").setFocus();
            }
        }, donotscroll]{}

    \newpage

    \TextField[width=10cm, height=10cm, charsize=12pt, 
        multiline=true, name=Partei1b, donotscroll]{}    
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If you enter text in the first field that exceeds the boundary of thi field, the cursor will automatically jump to the next field. But this automatism does not work when deleting text or pasting text. Also, I am not sure how to disable the annoying beep.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JasperHabicht. That is a nice solution and it also introduces me to JavaScript. The PDF will have some information prefilled in the form itself, so I will experiment...

Comment: Thank you @JasperHabicht. That is a nice solution and it also introduces me to JavaScript. The PDF will have some information prefilled in the form itself, so I will experiment...

Comment: @StefanosRotas The solution is not bullet-proof, but I think in some way or the other, there should be a way to do this.